# c++ win32 set cursor position

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mouse-cursor

I know which function to use but I can't get it to work right. I used `SetCursorPos()` the only problem is that it sets the cursor not to the windows coordinates but to the screen coordinates. i also tried the `ScreenToClient()` but it didn't work ethier.
Here is my code:

```
pt.x=113;
pt.y=280;
ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
SetCursorPos(pt.x, pt.y);
```

any idea?
I'm using win32. I hope that I given enough information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're approaching this slightly backwards.  The `SetCursorPos` function works in screen cordinates and you want to set the cursor based on window / client coordinates.  In order to do this you need to map from client to screen coordinates.  The function `ScreenToClient` does the opposite.  What you're looking for is `ClientToScreen`

For example:

```
ClientToScreen(hWnd, &pt);
SetCursorPos(pt.x,pt.y);
```

Documentation

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931003.aspx